# condensing the code or a one liner possible for this code in python

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have the following code and wondering if there is a simpler way to do this.
I am creating a list of tuples that holds letters from a string and the corresponding number from a list. here it is

```
s="hello"
lst=[1,2,3,4,5]
res = []
for i in range(len(lst)):
    res.append((s[i],lst[i]))
print res
```

The output is here which is correct. I am looking for condensed version if possible

```
[('h', 1), ('e', 2), ('l', 3), ('l', 4), ('o', 5)]
```

Comment: you can also try: `map(None, s, list)` but to me `zip()` is more semantic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this:

```
>>> s = "hello"
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> zip(s, lst)
[('h', 1), ('e', 2), ('l', 3), ('l', 4), ('o', 5)]
```

Note that here it works since the list and string are of equal length. otherwise, you might have truncations.

EDIT:

```
>>> s = "hell"
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> zip(s, lst)
[('h', 1), ('e', 2), ('l', 3), ('l', 4)]
```

you have the last item in `lst` missed out.

Comment: what does truncation means?

Comment: @user2708477 try: `zip('abc', [1, 2, 3, 4])`

Comment: If this is a problem try `itertools.zip_longest`

Answer (score 5):

Use [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function:

> This function returns a list of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th element from each of the argument sequences or iterables.

Demo:

```
>>> s="hello"
>>> lst=[1,2,3,4,5]
>>>
>>> zip(s, lst)
[('h', 1), ('e', 2), ('l', 3), ('l', 4), ('o', 5)]
```

Note that, in Python 3.x, [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) returns an iterator. You have to wrap the return value in `list(zip(s, lst))`, to make it a list.

To get an iterator in Python 2.x, use [itertools.`izip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip). Also, if the length of your sequences are not equal, then you can use [itertools.`izip_longest()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest).

```
>>> s="hell"  # len(s) < len(lst)
>>> lst=[1,2,3,4,5]
>>>
>>> zip(s, lst)  # Iterates till the length of smallest sequence
[('h', 1), ('e', 2), ('l', 3), ('l', 4)]
>>>
>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>> list(izip_longest(s, lst, fillvalue='-'))
[('h', 1), ('e', 2), ('l', 3), ('l', 4), ('-', 5)]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a snap with [zip](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> s="hello"
>>> lst=[1,2,3,4,5]
>>> zip(s, lst)
[('h', 1), ('e', 2), ('l', 3), ('l', 4), ('o', 5)]
>>>
```

Note that I wrote this in Python 2.x.  In Python 3.x, you will need to do this:

```
>>> s="hello"
>>> lst=[1,2,3,4,5]
>>> zip(s, lst)
<zip object at 0x021C36C0>
>>> list(zip(s, lst))
[('h', 1), ('e', 2), ('l', 3), ('l', 4), ('o', 5)]
>>>
```

This is because, as demonstarted, the Python 3.x `zip` returns a zip object instead of a list like it did in Python 2.x.

Answer (score 2):

i don't know if the list is always just monotonic numbers, but if they are, you can either replace it with range(), or use enumerate to make this one line:

```
s = 'hello'
sd = dict([reversed(x) for x in enumerate(s)])

s = 'hello'
zip(s, xrange(len(s)))
```

Comment: btw, `[x[::-1] for x in enumerate(s)]` is both shorter and usually faster than reversed(), for some reason...